# Create partition with exact size not to specific distance

Tags: partition, parted

How does one create a partition of exact size not to specific distance?

I have tried:

```
parted -a optimal /dev/sdd mkpart primary 0% 0%+1GB
# and...
parted -a optimal /dev/sdd mkpart primary 0% +1GB
```

To no avail.

How do I make it accept size instead of end distance?

Comment: What error messages do you get? Does `parted -a optimal /dev/sdd mkpart primary 0GB 10GB` work?

Comment: This would be so much easier for me to write my script if it existed :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `parted` only accepts absolutes, not `x+y`.

You could do it like this: (`+` interpreted by shell)

```
# start=1
# size=512
# parted /dev/loop0 unit mib mkpart primary $start $(($start+$size))
# parted /dev/loop0 unit mib print free
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 1000MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End      Size     File system  Name     Flags
        0.02MiB  1.00MiB  0.98MiB  Free Space
 1      1.00MiB  513MiB   512MiB                primary
        513MiB   1000MiB  487MiB   Free Space
```

...and if you want to append more, then

```
# start=$(($start+$size+1))
# size=128
# parted /dev/loop0 unit mib mkpart primary $start $(($start+$size))
# parted /dev/loop0 unit mib print free                           
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 1000MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End      Size     File system  Name     Flags
        0.02MiB  1.00MiB  0.98MiB  Free Space
 1      1.00MiB  513MiB   512MiB                primary
        513MiB   514MiB   1.00MiB  Free Space
 2      514MiB   642MiB   128MiB                primary
        642MiB   1000MiB  358MiB   Free Space
```

The `+1` is entirely optional, I just like leaving 1MiB free "bumpers" between partitions, for some reason.

If you want to deal with percentages, you can obtain the device size from the shell also, using `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/device`, so you can move all the math out of parted into a shell script. I do this to guarantee MiB-aligned partitions, as I'm never too sure about what `parted` means exactly by `-a optimal`.